# using wp_dequeue_style in a template file

Tags: wordpress

I am using a theme that uses bootstrap and jQuery UI. In a template file, a want to remove jQuery:

`custom.php`

```
/**
** Template Name: Custom
*
**/


get_header();

wp_deregister_style('jquery.ui.theme' );
wp_dequeue_style('jquery.ui.theme' );


?>

// my template goes here


<? php get_footer(); ?>
```

This doest not work.

I tried [putting the functions calls in a function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and call them with

```
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

**This is how the template includes the jQuery UI library:**

```
wp_enqueue_style('jquery.ui.theme', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery-ui.min.css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change  below variables with your template name, css file name and js file name same as css used name for stylesheet of jquery ui,

You have 2 global variables (**`$wp_styles`**,**`$wp_scripts`**) which wordpress use for print CSS and JS.

For CSS it use `$wp_styles` and for JS its `$wp_scripts`

IF you dont know the handler name of js file try `global $wp_scripts; print_r($wp_scripts);` and check for jquery ui (Jquery) handle name.

```
 - $Template_Name = 'Custom';
 - $css_file_name = 'jquery.ui.theme';
 - $js_file_name  = 'jquery.ui.theme';
```

Copy below code and add it in `functions.php`

```
function na_dequeue_function() {
        $Template_Name = 'Custom';
        $css_file_name = 'jquery.ui.theme';
        $js_file_name  = 'jquery.ui.theme';
        if( is_page_template($Template_Name) ) {
            ################ Remove styles #################
            global $wp_styles;
            $style_array = array();
            // Runs through the queue styles
            foreach($wp_styles->queue as $handle) :
                if( $css_file_name == $handle ) {
                    $style_array[] = $handle;
                }
            endforeach;
            wp_dequeue_style($style_array);
            wp_deregister_style($style_array);
            #################################
            ################ Remove Scripts #################
            global $wp_scripts;
            $script_array = array();
            // Runs through the queue scripts
            foreach($wp_scripts->queue as $handle) :
                if( $js_file_name == $handle ) {
                    $script_array[] = $handle;
                }
            endforeach;
            wp_dequeue_script($script_array);
            wp_dequeue_script($script_array);
            ################ Remove Scripts #################
        }
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'na_dequeue_function');
```

Comment: for `$Template_Name`, should I use the file name or the Template name specified in comments?

Comment: it should be the filename like `template-page.php` , Read more about [What does is_page_template() compare against?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/238640/what-does-is-page-template-compare-against?answertab=votes#tab-top)